# Add values ​in a new column in a data frame based on another column with r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame named df1:

| CITY | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| B | 6 | 4 |
| C | 9 | 2 |
| D | 8 | 2 |
| E | 9 | 5 |

And also I have the following dataframe named df2:

| CITY | X |
| --- | --- |
| C | 45 |
| E | 9 |

How can I add the information from df2 to df1 based on city name? The desired outcome is:

| CITY | V1 | V2 | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 0 | NA |
| B | 6 | 4 | NA |
| C | 9 | 2 | 45 |
| D | 8 | 2 | NA |
| E | 9 | 5 | 9 |

Comment: Please check the `left_join` function from the `tidyverse` package. Or the `merge` function frmo base R.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)